# Can anyone spot a mistake in this php/mysql UPDATE code - mysql_affected_rows() return is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code:

The first look up query-1 works fine..
BUT
The second query2 works as well but mysql_affected_rows() doesnt tell me if the record has been updated, why?

thanks.

---

```
$uemail  = 'driggg2@gmail.com';
$authkey = '2f4071bffda44aa30064364055687d13';

require_once ('./domainsiteconnect.php'); // Connect to the database.

if ( $uemail && $authkey)
{

echo "<br>--uemail: [$uemail] -- && -- [$authkey] --- ";

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE email='$uemail' AND actkey='$authkey' AND status='pending' ";

    $result1 = mysql_query ($query1);
    $num1 = mysql_num_rows ($result1);

    if ( $num1 == 1 )  // Exactly 1 rec found - Update member to verified.
    {
       echo '<br>+++ query1: successful +++>br>';

        $status = 'verified';

$query2 = " UPDATE member SET status='$status' WHERE email='$uemail'   ";    //AND actkey='$authkey'  ";
    //- $query2 = " UPDATE member SET status='$status' WHERE email='$uemail' AND actkey='$authkey'  ";

    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $num2 = mysql_affected_rows($result2);


        if ( $num2  )  //  updated? - inform user
        {

            echo "<br>--$uemail updated to verified --";
        }
        else
            echo "<br>--$uemail  verfication [update] failed --";

            $val1=mysql_errno();
        $val2=mysql_error();

        //-- 
echo '<br>['.$query2.']--<br>--['.$result2.']<br>val-1:'.$val1.'<br> val-2'.$val2;


            }

    }   //-- eof. if auth/email flags ok ---
```

========================

The resulting output is:

```
 --uemail: [driggg2@gmail.com] -- && -- [2f4071bffda44aa30064364055687d13] ---

 +++ query1: successful +++>br>

 Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/arif/public_html/amy/public/domainsite/verifyfirst.php on line 125

 --driggg2@gmail.com verfication [update] failed --
[ UPDATE member SET status='verified' WHERE email='driggg2@gmail.com'; ]--
--[1]
val-1:0
val-2
```

---

i think, the warning is because query2 doesnt return a resource-id that is needed by mysqL_affected_rows().

- both db and table are in utf8.
  what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Please tell me that these are **not** your real authentication details that you've just posted on a public website.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Try one thing: Right before the line that starts with $result2 = ... add the following code: echo $query2; and look at the output.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what is states is that [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) does not take any parameters. Within the context of the update is will output the affected rows. Thus, you need not pass the $result2.

Instead of

> $num2 = mysql_affected_rows($result2);

use

> $num2 = mysql_affected_rows();

Comment: I'm saying you must just use $num2 = mysql_affected_rows();

Comment: Because he is using mysql_num_rows and not mysql_affected_rows for the first query.

Comment: thank you. your suggestion has worked and mysql has stopped complaining. mysql is soooooo touchy & finnicky !

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, put the result of mysql_connect in mysql_affected_rows to eliminate the error message and get the actual affected number of rows.

Comment: That is exactly what goes wrong. You need to provide the connection identifier, not the result identifier. So just the output of mysql_connect. Or easier, no parameter as mentioned by JLC007.